# Django form ForeignKey database field not as dropdown

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I have a database model like, with a ForeignKey field.
From this model I created a form with

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
    foobar = models.ForeignKey(Foobar)
    bar = models.Charfield()
    foo = models.Charfield()

class FoobarForm():
    class Meta:
        model = Foobar
        fields = ['bar', 'foo']
```

If I add foobar to fields like: fields = ['foobar', 'foo', 'bar']
In html it is a dropdown control... but I wont a text input field.

How do I do that?

Comment: You might want to look into the django autocomplete plugins

Comment: If it is the only way. I do that. thx. :-)

Comment: That is not the only way, but it is the best way. Would you not want to provide an auto suggest feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
from django import forms

class FoobarForm():
    class Meta:
        model = Foobar

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FoobarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foobar'].widget = forms.TextInput()
```